# поиск буквы в строке

Tags: c++

допустим есть некоторое число, мы преобразуем его в строку (std::to_string)
есть ли возможность проверки каждого символа этой строки? допустим если в переменную а положить число 20. все это находится в цикле: и если число имеет "0", то флажок становится равным 1, это засчитывается. Возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: [man strchr](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно. Можно с помощью цикла пройтись по всем символам строки и сверить их с искомым символом:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::string s = std::to_string(n);
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) // цикл для итерации по символам строки
    {
      if (s[i] == '0') flag = true; // меняем значение flag на true, если текущий символ - это '0'
    }
    std::cout << flag;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: что в данном случае значит s.size()? количество элементов в строке?

Comment: `s.size()` возвращает длину строки `s`